# Gradle copy task after build

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

In Gradle it is easy to define tasks to run after the build.

```
task finalize1 << {
    println('finally1!')
}
build.finalizedBy(finalize1)
```

This works as expected. But now I want to execute a copy task at the end.

```
task finalize (type: Copy) {
    def zipFile = file('data/xx.zip')
    def outputDir = file("data/")
    println('Unzip..')
    from zipTree(zipFile)
    into outputDir
}
build.finalizedBy(finalize)
```

This does not work anymore. I see the "Unzip" output at the beginning of the build (I need the extract at the end).

```
Unzip..
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:jar
:bootRepackage
:assemble
...
```

`<<` does the trick it seems but how I can I merge these two?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to. You see `Unzip...` at the beginning of the build, but it does not mean that Gradle is executing your task at that moment.

This message is printed in console when Gradle starts to configure your copy task, e.g. adding paths to inputs and outputs. Real execution is done after build. To verify that you can use `doLast` closure:

```
task finalize (type: Copy) {
   doLast { println 'running now' }
   ...
}
```

Code inside `doLast` block will be executed after build.

P.S. Don't move the rest of your task code (`from zipTree(zipFile)`, etc) inside `doLast` closure, it won't work.